# Python set problems

Tags: python, set

**How do I delete an (user) input string stored in a variable from a set IN PYTHON?**

Its from this task:

There is an unknown set of objects named mystery_set which has been predefined. You don't have access to this set.

Write a program that deletes the input string (stored in the variable string) from the mystery_set. It is NOT guaranteed that the string is an element of the mystery_set. Don't forget to take that into account!

Don't print anything!

I tried this code but runtime error:

> ```
> # mystery_set has been defined
> string = input()
>
> # delete string from mystery_set
> mystery_set.remove(string)
> ```

Should I check if string is an element in mystery_set as a way

Thank you

Comment: What is  the error you're getting?

Comment: This seems like a very simple thing to do: only remove the element if you've checked and it's in the set...

Comment: try `if string in mystery_set: mystery_set.remove(string)`

Comment: There's a dedicated `discard` method for this.

Comment: @TomKarzes I would call the approach of adding and removing highly unidiomatic.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well, it would only be idiomatic if there weren't another way to do it that didn't involve membership testing (and if membership testing weren't allowed).  As it is, the `discard` method is what's needed, which I hadn't known about, so it's a moot point.

Comment: @TomKarzes well, no, then `try-except` would be idiomatic

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You seem to have a private library that defines what you consider to be idiomatic.  I may prefer the `try`/`except` approach, which I had also mentioned, but keep in mind that it may possibly be less efficient than `add`/`remove`.  You could time them both to find out.  If I'm not mistaken, there's a fair amount of overhead associated with `try`.

Comment: @TomKarzes no, not private. This is a well-known, it's referred to as "Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission" (EAFP). It's even in the [official glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html) where it is referred to as the "common Python coding style". This is in contrast with the "Look before you leap" (LBYL) style, common to languages like C and Java.

Comment: @TomKarzes as for performance, it depends on what you expect. Handlling an actual exception can be costly, but if there is no exception raised, there is no performance impact. So it can be *faster* if you expect the item to usually be in the set, slower if you expect it to usually not be in the set. In any case, this would only really matter if you were trying to micro-optimize a tight loop or something.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well, as I said, it's a moot point since `discard` exists and does exactly what's needed.  I should have realized something like that had to exist.  The `set` methods `remove` and `discard` are analogous to the string methods `index` and `find`, in terms of how they handle a missing item.